# My Unity Desktop Broken because of MyUnity

Tags: unity, software-sources

I've just installed MyUnity in Ubuntu 12.04 and changed the system font style but suddenly it crashed. I tried to boot it again but it crash again and again. So I log in via guest and remove MyUnity from software center but when I tried to log in via admin user, it crashed again! How do I solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Answer (score 2):

can you open your terminal ?

OK either in terminal or press **ctrl+alt+F1** and login there & then do as

```
unity --reset
```

restart your PC and try again .

Comment: What code I should type before typing "unity --reset"? because when I typed that instanly, it's said that the login is incorrect. And which password I should type, keyring password or not?

Comment: Still incorrect. I've tried 10 times so far.

Comment: sorry, it was CLI I think. But I've tried it in terminal but nothing happens.

Comment: if its in terminal, could you give me the code of what you did and what you got . thank you , :)